# MySQL: How to decrease sleep process's time out?

Tags: mysql, rails, timeout

When I run 'show processlist;', then I get so many sleep processes.

[image: show processlist;]

I set wait_timeout and interactive_timeout to 60 in my.cnf. But, sleep process is not died when time 60 on processlist. I found that sleep process is died when time is 7900. What happend?? How can I decrease sleep process's time out?

If you need other information, I will give information as I possible.

**UPDATE**

I use root, read_only and deploy account on mysql. And I found root and read_only accounts run correct. Query -> Sleep -(60sec)-> release process.

But deploy account, using to connect between rails server and mysql, run wrong. Query -> Sleep -(7900sec)-> release. So, I think that deploy account or Rails is problem. However, I dont have any idea to fix this.

Comment: which web server are you using? puma, unicorn? passenger?

Answer (score 1):

### What does `sleep` mean?

MySQL process has completed the execution of query, but the client(Rails) doesn't exit.

### Why does it happen?

Either puma or unicorn, they are using persistent connections to database, then it's normal to have lots of idle connection, the state of which is sleep.

### Should I worry about it?

If those sleep connections come from Rails web application and less than the configuration of database connection pool size, there is nothing to worry.

### How to fix it?

```
set global wait_timeout=XXX; // wait_timeout is for non-interactive sessions.
set global interactive_timeout=XXX;  // interactive_time is for interactive sessions
```

### Reference

1. [Should I worry about mysql sleep status process in processlist?](https://serverfault.com/questions/281420/should-i-worry-about-mysql-sleep-status-process-in-processlist)
2. [Mysql show processlist lists many processes sleep and info = null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053744/mysql-show-processlist-lists-many-processes-sleep-and-info-null)

Answer (score 0):

to check your idle process timeout you can connect to `MySQL` then execute the following command:

```
show variables like "%timeout%";
```

you need to check `wait_timeout` and `interactive_timeout` from the results based on those values you can execute the following commands from MySQL to set them:

```
set global wait_timeout=XXX; -- where XXX equal value less than the original one
set global interactive_timeout=XXX;  -- where XXX equal value less than the original one
```

Comment: Those settings will take effect only as new connections occur; existing connections will run until the old timeout.  (Or you could kill them.)

Comment: These settings are good as long as application is written in such a way if there is  threadpooling, these timeouts might cause errors and they should have logic to respawn the threads upon demand.